# How to do a merge in a git monorepo?

Tags: git, merge, version-control, monorepo

Let's say I work on Product A. My colleague work on Product C. Each product relies on a library that is shared between the two products, Library B.

The components are stored in the SCM as a flat tree, in traditional monorepo fashion.

My colleague and I start developing a feature that impacts all 3 components. So we create a branch off the trunk, and start working on the feature. This feature takes some time, and many commits. Each commit affects either component A & B in the same commit, or B & C in the same commit, or one of the 3 components individually.

Finally, we get the feature working between the two products, and it is time to merge it back to the "trunk". Because of the time taken on the development branch, all 3 of the components have changed on the trunk branch, making this merge a "big" merge.

The problem is, I'm not qualified to handle the merge of component C (not my product). My colleague is not able to handle the merge of component A (not his product).

In a SCM like Subversion, where merges can be done on a file-by-file basis, this is not a problem. I can merge A & B, my colleague then merges C. But in Git, this is not possible. This is because Git only performs merges at the commit level, and so will try to merge all 3 components simultaneously. So how do we merge the branch back into trunk?

My first thought is to rewrite the history in some fashion, either separating out each tree into it's own branch, or by reordering the commits so that all the A commits are contiguous, followed by the B commits, and then by the C commits. This would allow us to do separate merges. But then, we've lost what originally happened. It's possible the new commits won't build, or the tests won't work. We had to lose all that just to work with the system, which doesn't seem like a good tradeoff to me.

The other option is to get both of us together to do the merge at the same terminal. (which may not be a bad thing, honestly). But if an issue comes up in my product that takes time to handle, then my colleague is delayed as well.

I know companies like Microsoft have git monorepos. How do they handle this problem?

Comment: Some hosted git platforms (such as Azure DevOps) provide a way for multiple to collaborate on conflict resolution within a single PR. If your hosting platform doesn't support this, you can create a new branch from your dev branch and merge trunk into it. You resolve the merges of the A and B parts, and just check in the merge markers in C. Your colleague can then make a new commit into the new branch to resolve the conflicts in C. You can test this branch to validate the changes, and you can submit a PR from it back into the trunk.

Comment: Are you asking how you resolve conflicts in this case, or how you perform the merge, even if it lacks conflicts?

Comment: @bk2204 I'm not referring to the exact mechanics of how to perform the merge. I'm referring to being able to make sure that the merge is correct, conflicts or not. Even a merge with no conflicts can cause incorrect behavior at runtime. Since I'm not familiar with component C, I cannot say - "yes this merge has produced a good result." Tests are important in this regard, but what if the tests are in a poor state?

Comment: @RaymondChen I've never used a hosted platform before. My company doesn't use any, so I'm not sure about the workflow you are talking about with "conflict resolution." However, I think your second part is probably the answer I'm looking for. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the basic answer is that the merging has to be done in a separate branch, where it is allowed to be messy or incomplete, before merging to the 'trunk'.

Another solution is for the team to follow trunk based development (see [trunkbaseddevelopment.com](https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com)), and break the work into smaller chunks that can be turned on and off at will through feature flags, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Takking about PRs, you could create the PR and ask your friend to review the parts related to what they command.... if they have comments, you take care of them until everybody is happy.